# Using sqlalchemy MappedAsDataclass as Model doesn't work for init=False fields

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi, pydantic

I'm trying to use the dataclass coming from sqlalchemy as the definition of my model, to be able to validate FastAPI request payload as follows:

```py
from sqlalchemy import Identity
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapped_column
from sqlalchemy.orm import MappedAsDataclass
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient


class Base(MappedAsDataclass, DeclarativeBase):
    pass

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "user_account"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(init=False, primary_key=True, server_default=Identity(always=True, start=1, increment=1, minvalue=1, cycle=False))
    name: Mapped[str]

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/user")
def create_user(user: User):
    return True

client = TestClient(app)

def test_add_user():
    response = client.post("/user", json={"name": "john"})
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

When I run the test, the `response` variable returns the following error:

```json
{"detail":[{"loc":["body","id"],"msg":"field required","type":"value_error.missing"}]}
```

The problem is, ID is an identity column, so I don't need it in the constructor, that's why I set the `init=False`. If I remove it, then the error changes:

```json
{"detail":[{"loc":["body"],"msg":"__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'","type":"type_error"}]}
```

It makes sense, now my payload is incomplete, since ID is missing, but the thing is, I'm trying to create a new user, so it's expected that ID will be empty. What am I missing here? How to use identity IDs together with pydantic (without duplicating the User class)?

I tried to use the `sqlalchemy` dataclass as a model for FastAPI, but FasAPI (or pydantic in this case) doesn't understand what an `Identity` field is and makes it mandatory in every request (during the payload validation).

Thanks!